# Use PullParser to deserialize Range in Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to convert some json `{ "range": {"start": 1, "stop": 10} }` into a `Range` object equivalent to `Range.new(1,10)`.

It seems that if I want to do this in my `Foo` struct I'll need a custom converter (see below) which uses the `JSON::PullParser` to consume each token. I tried things like the below to see if I could understand how the pull parser is supposed to be used. But it looks like it expects everything to be a string and chokes on the first Int it finds. So the following isn't helpful but illustrates what I'm confused about:

```
require "json"

module RangeConverter
  def self.from_json(pull : JSON::PullParser)
    pull.read_object do |key, key_location|
      puts key # => puts `start` then chokes on the `int`
               # Expected String but was Int at 1:22
    end
    Range.new(1,2)
  end
end

  
struct Foo
  include JSON::Serializable
    
  @[JSON::Field(converter: RangeConverter)]
  property range : Range(Int32, Int32)
end

Foo.from_json %({"range": {"start": 1, "stop": 10}})
```

The only way I was able to figure this out was to just read the raw json string and work with it directly but it feels like I'm side-stepping the parser because I don't understand it. The following works:

```
require "json"

module RangeConverter
  def self.from_json(pull : JSON::PullParser)
    h = Hash(String, Int32).from_json(pull.read_raw)
    Range.new(h["start"],h["stop"])
  end
end

  
struct Foo
  include JSON::Serializable
    
  @[JSON::Field(converter: RangeConverter)]
  property range : Range(Int32, Int32)
end

Foo.from_json %({"range": {"start": 1, "stop": 10}})
```

So how am I actually supposed to be using the Parser here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latter option isn't bad at all. It just reuses the implementation from a `Hash` but it's fully workable and composable. The only downside is it needs to allocate and then discard that `Hash`.

Based on [this sample](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/8de7f2d062d7bc7d3c89d960c933e0df95511db4/src/json/any.cr#L41) I deduce that you're expected to call `.begin_object?` first. But actually that's just a nicety for error detection. The main thing is that you're also supposed to explicitly read ("consume") the values, [based on this sample](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/11e1053f9ba66cae9f8c9ba9de7c62ac9906dbd2/src/json/from_json.cr#L186). In the code below this is represented with `Int32.new(pull)`.

```
require "json"

module RangeConverter
  def self.from_json(pull : JSON::PullParser)
    start = stop = nil
    unless pull.kind.begin_object?
      raise JSON::ParseException.new("Unexpected pull kind: #{pull.kind}", *pull.location)
    end
    pull.read_object do |key, key_location|
      case key
      when "start"
        start = Int32.new(pull)
      when "stop"
        stop = Int32.new(pull)
      else
        raise JSON::ParseException.new("Unexpected key: #{key}", *key_location)
      end
    end
    raise JSON::ParseException.new("No start", *pull.location) unless start
    raise JSON::ParseException.new("No stop", *pull.location) unless stop
    Range.new(start, stop)
  end
end

  
struct Foo
  include JSON::Serializable
    
  @[JSON::Field(converter: RangeConverter)]
  property range : Range(Int32, Int32)
end

p Foo.from_json %({"range": {"start": 1, "stop": 10}})
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Oleh Prypin is great. As he said, the second approach is good except that it allocates a Hash so it consumes extra memory.

Instead of Hash you can use a NamedTuple which is allocated on the stack so it's much more efficient. This is a good use case for such type:

```
require "json"

module RangeConverter
  def self.from_json(pull : JSON::PullParser)
    tuple = NamedTuple(start: Int32, stop: Int32).new(pull)
    tuple[:start]..tuple[:stop]
  end
end

struct Foo
  include JSON::Serializable

  @[JSON::Field(converter: RangeConverter)]
  property range : Range(Int32, Int32)
end

p Foo.from_json %({"range": {"start": 1, "stop": 10}})
```

An alternative to `NamedTuple` is to use a plain struct with getters, which is what `record` is for:

```
require "json"

record JSONRange, start : Int32, stop : Int32 do
  include JSON::Serializable

  def to_range
    start..stop
  end
end

module RangeConverter
  def self.from_json(pull : JSON::PullParser)
    JSONRange.new(pull).to_range
  end
end

struct Foo
  include JSON::Serializable

  @[JSON::Field(converter: RangeConverter)]
  property range : Range(Int32, Int32)
end

p Foo.from_json %({"range": {"start": 1, "stop": 10}})
```